# Apache HTTPD - recursively deny specific file extensions and/or subdirs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have an Apache 2.4 web server, and in its `htdocs` folder, there is a complicated structure of directories and subdirectories.

Is it possible to create a single, top-level `.htaccess` file that would deny specific file extensions (e.g. `.bak`)
and/or traversing into specific directory names (e.g. `.git`)
for the whole subdirectory structure?

E.g., I would like to respond with `HTTP 403 Forbidden` when requested:

```
htdocs/index.html.bak
htdocs/aaa/bbb/ccc/login.php.bak
htdocs/foooooooo/.git/subdir/some_pic.png
```

If not via `.htaccess`, then perhaps this can be achieved via `httpd.conf`?

Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule \.bak$ - [F]`, `RewriteRule /\.git/ - [F]` should already more or less do the trick.

Comment: Only for a `.git` folder on the root level you would need an additional rule - because there is no `/` in front of it then in the path that rewriterule matches against, but we can't make the slash in the rule shown on the previous comment optional (because you don't want it to match on `foo.git/`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks! I ended up with the following `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.bak$          - [F]
RewriteRule (^|/)\.git($|/) - [F]
```

Of course, this line in `httpd.conf` has to be uncommented first:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```